# JQ: access object by key variable

Tags: jq

Assume I have an object 'variables' containing a variable amount of unspecified other objects:

```
{
   "id":5,
   "variables":{
      "variable1":{
         "isSecret":null,
         "value":"value1"
      },
      "variable2":{
         "isSecret":null,
         "value":"value2"
      }
   }
}
```

What I need is a way to access both key name and the value of 'value' in the same loop.

I tried the following:

```
echo $service_connection | jq -r '.variables | keys[]' | while read variable; do
    echo $variable
    echo $service_connection | jq --arg var "$variable" -c '.variables[$var].value'
done
```

This gives me the following output:

```
variable1
null
variable2
null
```

To me, it seems like I would need something like

```
'.variables.$var'
```

or

```
'.variables.[$var]'
```

But jq can't parse it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `to_entries` to split up the `.variables` object into an array of key-value pairs is also an option:

```sh
jq -r '.variables | to_entries[] | "\(.key): \(.value.value)"'
```

```json
variable1: value1
variable2: value2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DVKwasnPSW)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a bash intervention with a `while` read loop, do it all with `jq`

```
jq -r '.variables | keys_unsorted[] as $k | "\($k) \(.[$k].value)"'
```

produces a result as

```
variable1 value1
variable2 value2
```

[jqplay - demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rmGBCKs_QT)

Answer (score 0):

```
jq '.variables | with_entries(.value |= .value)'
```

```json
{
  "variable1": "value1",
  "variable2": "value2"
}
```